# NameError: name 'playerMovement' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm here to ask what is the problem with my code? I'm making a game engine, and I thought the easiest way to sort player types would be putting them into a different script and using them there. However, I am having a slight issue doing that, and have no clue how to fix it.

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Harry Court\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\projects\Game Engine\main.py", line 48, in <module> topDownPlayerControls() NameError: name 'topDownPlayerControls' is not defined
```

P.S: If there is an easier way to do this, please tell me!

main.py

```
import pygame
from playerSelection import *


import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPWSTR, UINT


# Window Size
display_w = 1366
display_h = 768

# Initialize and Set Display
pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Joker Engine (Version Undecided) - By Harrison Court")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Ctypes ID's
IDYES = 6
IDNO = 7

x = (display_w * 0.45)
y = (display_h * 0.8)

# Colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

running = True

gameDisplay.fill(white)

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            # Misc.
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quitWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Warning!", 4)

                # Confirm they want to leave.
                if quitWindow == IDYES:
                    quit()

        topDownPlayerControls()

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

playerSelection.py:

```
import pygame

from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu

import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPWSTR, UINT

x = (300)
y = (300)

playerImg = pygame.image.load('Player.png')

class playerMovement():

    def player(x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

    def topDownPlayerControls():

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Left & Right
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
                print("Left")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
                print("Right")

            # Up & Down
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5
                print("Down")

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
                print("Up")

        # If no keys are pressed, do this...
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
                y_change = 0

        # Player Movement
        x += x_change
        y += y_change
```

Updated Script:

main.py:

```
import pygame
from playerSelection import *
from gui import *
from tkinter import *

import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPWSTR, UINT

# Define stuff
player = playerMovement()

# Window Size
display_w = 1366
display_h = 768

# Initialize and Set Display
pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
pygame.display.set_caption("The Joker Engine (Version Undecided) - By Harrison Court")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Ctypes ID's
IDYES = 6
IDNO = 7

x = (display_w * 0.45)
y = (display_h * 0.8)

# Colours
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)

running = True

gameDisplay.fill(white)

# Make sure the game isn't dying on us.
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            # Misc.
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quitWindow = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Are you sure you want to quit?", "Warning!", 4)

                # Confirm they want to leave.
                if quitWindow == IDYES:
                    quit()

    player.displayPlayer(x,y)
    player.topDownPlayerControls


pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

playerSelection.py:

```
import pygame

from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Menu

import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPWSTR, UINT

x = (300)
y = (300)

display_w = 1366
display_h = 768

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_w, display_h))
playerImg = pygame.image.load('Player.png')

class playerMovement():

    def displayPlayer(self,x,y):
        gameDisplay.blit(playerImg, (x,y))

    def topDownPlayerControls(self):

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Left & Right
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
                print("Left")
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
                print("Right")

            # Up & Down
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5
                print("Down")

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
                print("Up")

        # If no keys are pressed, do this...
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP: 
                y_change = 0

        # Player Movement
        x += x_change
        y += y_change
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Also, maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see any places where you try to instantiate a `playerMovement` object.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry Court\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\projects\Game Engine\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    topDownPlayerControls()
NameError: name 'topDownPlayerControls' is not defined`

Comment: @HarryCourt functions within classes need at least one argument. I suggest trying to change `def topDownPlayerControls():` to `def topDownPlayerControls(self)`

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is saying that the function `topDownPlayerControls` is not defined.  This is because you are trying to call it as a free function.  However, this function is defined within the `playerMovement` class. So, you would first need to create a `playerMovement` object, and then call the `topDownPlayerControls` function on that object.  It would look something like this:

```
player = playerMovement()
player.topDownPlayerControls()
```

It looks like you will have a number of other fails after that, but I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Comment: Thanks Tim! But unfortunately, I've come across another error! 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry Court\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\projects\Game Engine\main.py", line 51, in <module>
    player.topDownPlayerControls()
TypeError: topDownPlayerControls() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`    -- How can I fix this? e.e

Comment: @HarryCourt RThomP actually answered this problem already.  In your definition of the `topDownPlayerControls` function, you need to supply at least one argument, like this:  `def topDownPlayerControls(self)`.

Comment: @HarryCourt Note that even though you added an argument to the definition of `topDownPlayerControls`, you will still call it with 0 arguments, like `player.topDownPlayerControls()`.  This is because `player` is automatically passed as the first argument, so under the covers, you really are calling `topDownPlayerControls` with one argument.

Comment: And even once that error is fixed you'll be getting other errors @HarryCourt

Comment: So, it appears that it's working fine now. No crashes or errors, but it doesn't show the player or print anything when I press the keys. How would I instance it into the scene?

Comment: You have to call the `player` function:  `player.player(x, y)`.  Perhaps that function should be named something like `displayPlayer` to make this code a bit clearer.

Comment: Oop, didn't see the extra comment symbol below, whoops! I think I'm getting closer! But I get this error; `TypeError: displayPlayer() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. The two arguments being x,y. But where does the third come in?

Comment: @HarryCourt This is the same problem again. You need to declare `def displayPlayer(self, x, y)`.

Comment: Sorry for the inactivity, and sorry for asking for so, so much questions >///<. But it no longer crashes, but doesn't move the player or even print anything now! I've updated the script above ^^

Comment: That might be because `x` and `y` are tuples instead of numbers. Try replacing `x=(300)` and `y=(300)` with `x=300` and `y=300`.

Comment: Also, you have global variables `x` and `y` defined in both files. Do they have the same or different meaning? If different, then give them different names.